# Java: ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, object, io

```
    public void bar(String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    Map map = (HashMap) in.readObject();
}
```

I'm trying to understand what this piece of code does.

We create a stream, so we'll be able to read from this file. What does this `ObjectInputStream` do? Do we read object and make a map out of it? I clearly don't understand, and I'll be glad for your help.

Comment: Did you read the api doc for [`ObjectInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)?

Comment: Frankly I didn't. I don't get along with them that well.

Comment: Err, if you don't do your research people here are likely not going to help, and you won't understand even if you get help.

Comment: Ok, I'll read them before I ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is it is reading a `HashMap` that was previously written to the file using corresponding `Out`/`Write` methods.

Answer (score 6):

`ObjectInputStream` will read Object serialized in file by `ObjectOutputStream`

```
public void bar(String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName); //1
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn); //2
    Map map = (HashMap) in.readObject(); //3
}
```

this code will

1. create InputStream from `fileName` (String, absolute path to file)
2. create ObjectInputStream, to read objects saved in that file
3. will create `HashMap` object, saved to `Map map` variable

So that mean, in file, there is a object of type `HashMap` which will be casted to `Map` with this code

Comment: So does 'in' suppose to contain only maps? if not, will it know to locate the map that inside the file by itself? should I declare on java.lang.ClassCastException? Thanks a lot!

Comment: See my response. Best to try it out yourself; but yes, it will throw exception if the contained object is not a HashMap.

Comment: Usually you do know what object type you read from file, but yes, exception will be thrown if it is not `HashMap` object. And `no, in is not supposed to contain only HashMap objects`

Comment: @Dear Hemal: I can't understand from your answer if it suppose to contain -only- HashMaps? perhaps the first object should be one? or does it suppose to contain -only one object- and this object should be a map? How do I even put a map into the file? Writing it's definition as I do in java?

Comment: @Nir, no, file will contain objects but not `only HashMap or Map` objects. Writing object into file is done via `FileOutputStream`, `ObjectOutputStream` and `Object implementing Serializable interface`